# Rewrite php to JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a php that sends POST request to server, it works fine:

```
<?php

$params = array ('id' => '3','title' => 'test', 'description' => 'testdescription');

$query = http_build_query ($params);

$contextData = array ( 
                'method' => 'POST',
                'header' => "Connection: close\r\n".
                            "Content-Length: ".strlen($query)."\r\n",
                'content'=> $query );

$context = stream_context_create (array ( 'http' => $contextData ));

$result =  file_get_contents (
                  'http://95.85.57.158/api/v3/projects/3/issues?private_token=XXXXXX',  // page url
                  false,
                  $context);

// Server response is now stored in $result variable so you can process it



var_dump($result);
?>
```

Now I want to rewrite  it to JS (jquery) and so I get:

```
  $(".submit").click(function() {


  var dataString = {id:"3",title:"test",description:'test'};
//alert (dataString);return false;
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://95.85.57.158/api/v3/projects/3/issues?private_token=XXXX",
  data: dataString,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function() {
    alert('done');
    }});
return false;

  });
});
```

But i get 404 error on button click( Can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is this ip yours: 95.85.57.158, because if its not , your browser wont let use it as it is cross domain problem

Comment: what does the '.submit' DOMObject looks like? You are either submiting a form to an invalid address of trying to reach an invalid address. Try to add ".preventDefault()" in your click callback Oh wait nevermind. There are just some confusing "})" in your code

Comment: Its mine but it is on the other domain... How can it be solved? Maybe just give an idea...

Comment: You should have a look at (and implement) CORS if the web app location and ajax url are different.

Answer (score 0):

404 means that the Url

```
http://95.85.57.158/api/v3/projects/3/issues
```

is not existing but i think you know that.

In you jQuery Post, put Token in the dataString.

And test this Url

```
http://95.85.57.158/api/v3/projects/3/issues
```

In your browser for see if it is existing yet.

Comment: Thank you for help, but puting Token in the dataString didn't solve the problem... Regarding URL it 100% right as php code works for sure.

Comment: If i test the URL, i've a 401 not authorised. Not a 404. You have to loggin before calling this URL.